# Loop across many datasets to get one summary table

Tags: loops, stata

I have about 100 datasets in Stata. I want to loop across all of them to get one summary table for the proportion of people across all datasets who are taking a drug aceinhib.  I can write code which produces a table for each dataset, but what I want is a summary of all these tables in one table.

Here is an example using just 5 datasets:

```
forval i=1/5 {
      capture use "FILEADDRESS\FILENAME`i'", clear 
      table aceinhib            
      capture save "FILEADDRESS\NEW_FILENAME`i'", replace
}
```

This gives me:

```
----------------------
 aceinhib |      Freq.
----------+-----------
        0 |    1578935
        1 |    138,961
----------------------

----------------------
 aceinhib |      Freq.
----------+-----------
        0 |    5671774
        1 |    421,732
----------------------

----------------------
 aceinhib |      Freq.
----------+-----------
        0 |    2350391
        1 |    198,875
----------------------

----------------------
 aceinhib |      Freq.
----------+-----------
        0 |    884,660
        1 |     51,087
----------------------

----------------------
 aceinhib |      Freq.
----------+-----------
        0 |    1470388
        1 |    130,614
----------------------
```

What I want is:

```
----------------------
 aceinhib |      Freq.
----------+-----------
        0 |    11956148
        1 |    941269
----------------------
```

-- namely, the combined results of the 5 tables above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this pattern:

```
scalar a = 0 
scalar b = 0 

quietly forval i = 1/1000 {
    sysuse auto, clear 
    count if foreign 
    scalar a = scalar(a) + r(N) 
    count if !foreign 
    scalar b = scalar(b) + r(N) 
}
gen double count = cond(_n == 1, scalar(a), cond(_n == 2, scalar(b), .))  
gen which = cond(_n == 1, "Foreign", cond(_n == 2, "Domestic", ""))  
list which count in 1/2
```

Just cumulate counts from one file to another. For the real problem, don't read in the same dataset, repeatedly, but different files in a loop.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you very much. This worked out for me.

Answer (score 0):

If all files have the same structure, you could `append` them into one file before your `table` command. The following solutions also rely on `aceinhib` being coded as 0/1. If the files are not too large to append, it could be as simple as:

```
use "FILEADDRESS\FILENAME1", clear

forvalues i = 2/100 {
    append using "FILEADDRESS\FILENAME`i'"
}

table aceinhib
```

If the resulting data file from `append` is too large, and there are no weights involved, you may continue as you have and employ the `replace` option for `table`:

```
forvalues i = 1/100 {
    use "FILENAME`i'", clear
    table aceinhib, replace
    rename table1 freq
    save "NEW_FILENAME`i'"
}

use "NEW_FILENAME1", clear
forvalues i = 2/100 {
    append using "NEW_FILENAME`i'"
}

collapse (sum) freq, by(aceinhib)
list
```

Note that this approach will create data files containing the individual frequency tables. A third approach relies on storing the results of `tab` into a matrix for each iteration of the loop, and adding them to another matrix to store the cumulative freq of 0/1 values for aceinhib in each dataset:

```
mat b = (0\0)
forvalues i = 1/100 {
    use "`FILENAME`i''", clear
    tab aceinhib, matcell(aceinhib`i')
    mat aceinhib = aceinhib + aceinhib`i'
}
mat list aceinhib
```

This is how I would approach the problem, although there may be cleaner solutions leveraging user written packages or other base Stata functionality that I haven't included here.

Comment: They are too big to append (and I actually have much more than 100) thats why I want to use the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will point you in a useful direction.

```
clear
tempfile working
save `working', emptyok
forval i=1/5{
    quietly use "FILEADDRESS\FILENAME`i'", clear 
    * replace "somevariable" with the name of a variable that is never missing 
    collapse (count) N=somevariable, by(aceinhib)
    append using `working'
    quietly save `working', replace
    }
use `working', clear
collapse (sum) N, by(aceinhib)
list
```